# Cannot Read Property 'value' of null when input given explicit value

Tags: javascript, html

I know this type of issue has been asked about a bunch before, and most of the time it is fixed due to the element IDs being different. However, I have copied and pasted the ID from the element into the JS code, and am still geting the error, even when I have used value="#" on the input field. Any ideas would be helpful.

```js
//Var
var numsessionsvar = parseInt(document.getElementById("numsessions").value);
var timeofdayvar = document.getElementById("timeofday").value;
var dayvar = document.getElementById("day").value;
var price = "";

//Pricing

function calculate() {
    if (timeofday = "0700" || "0800") {
        price = "25";
    }

    if (timeofday = "0900" || "1000" || "1100") {
    price = "Normal Rates";
    }

    if (timeofday = "1200" || "1300") {
        if (day = "Saturday") {
            price = "20";
        }
        else {
            price = "30";
        }
    }

    if (timeofday = "1400" || "1500") {
        price = "20";
    }

    if (timeofday = "1600" || "1700") {
        if (day = "Saturday") {
            price = "20";
        }
        else {
            price = "Normal Rate";
        }
    }

    if (timeofday = "1800") {
        price = "Normal Rates";
    }

    if (timeofday = "1900") {
        price = "30";
    }

    if (timeofday = "2000") {
        price = "20";
    }

    //Output
    var total = price * numsessions;
    var output = "£" + total + ".00";
    document.getElementById("output").value = output;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <input type="number" id="numsessions" min="1" max="5" value="1" />
        <select id="day">
                <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
                <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
                <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
                <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
        </select>
        <select id="timeofday">
                <option value="0700">0700</option>
                <option value="0800">0800</option>
                <option value="0900">0900</option>
                <option value="1000">1000</option>
                <option value="1100">1100</option>
                <option value="1200">1200</option>
                <option value="1300">1300</option>
                <option value="1400">1400</option>
                <option value="1500">1500</option>
                <option value="1600">1600</option>
                <option value="1700">1700</option>
                <option value="1800">1800</option>
                <option value="1900">1900</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
        </select>
        <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
        <input type="text" id="output" />
</body>
```

Comment: `option vaule="1500"` is a typo, right?

Comment: Where is the details of the calculate function?

Comment: @AndyTheos Yup, just caught and fixed it, issue persists.

Comment: You define numsessionsvar but then use numsessions. Is it also a typo ? Idem for other variables

Comment: @shakeelosmani Should be in the JS code, under the //Pricing comment.

Comment: @Florian.C Yup, however that isn't where the main issue with the code is, see post.

Comment: When I changed to numsessionsvar it seems to work fine? What issue are you facing?

Comment: @shakeelosmani When I run the code, I get an error on line 2 saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" as was mentioned at the top.

Comment: code works fine for me, offcourse I moved the value reading inside the function like so:

function calculate() {


  //Var
var numsessionsvar = parseInt(document.getElementById("numsessions").value);
var timeofdayvar = document.getElementById("timeofday").value;
var dayvar = document.getElementById("day").value;
var price = "";

The reason being it should be read on button click not on dom load

Comment: @shakeelosmani So it's a case of it trying to read the value of the inputs before they exist then? Good to know for the future, Thanks!

Comment: Also all your boolean checks are wrong, they should use at least == and preferably ===, i have fixed them too

Answer (score 1):

You're making plenty of errors and mistakes in your code.

First of all, here's a working snippet then I have some notes that may help you:

```js
function calculate() {
    var numsessions = parseInt(document.getElementById("numsessions").value), timeofday = document.getElementById("timeofday").value, dayvar = document.getElementById("day").value, price = "";
    if (timeofday == "0700" || timeofday == "0800") {
        price = 25;
    }

    if (timeofday == "0900" || timeofday == "1000" || timeofday == "1100") {
      //price = "Normal Rates";
        price = 25;
        
    }
if (timeofday == "1200" || timeofday == "1300") { 
        if (day = "Saturday") {
            price = 20;
        }
        else {
            price = 30;
        }
    }

    if (timeofday == "1400" || timeofday == "1500") {
        price = 20;
    }

    if (timeofday == "1600" || timeofday == "1700") {
        if (day = "Saturday") {
            price = 20;
        }
        else {
            //price = "Normal Rates";
              price = 25;
        }
    }

    if (timeofday == "1800") {
        //price = "Normal Rates";
        price = 25;
    }
if (timeofday == "1900") {
        price = 30;
    }

    if (timeofday == "2000") {
        price = 20;
    }

    //Output
    var total = price * numsessions, output = "£" + total + ".00";
    document.getElementById("output").value = output;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numsessions" min="1" max="5" value="1" />
        <select id="day">
                <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
                <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
                <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
                <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
        </select>
        <select id="timeofday">
                <option value="0700">0700</option>
                <option value="0800">0800</option>
                <option value="0900">0900</option>
                <option value="1000">1000</option>
                <option value="1100">1100</option>
                <option value="1200">1200</option>
                <option value="1300">1300</option>
                <option value="1400">1400</option>
                <option value="1500">1500</option>
                <option value="1600">1600</option>
                <option value="1700">1700</option>
                <option value="1800">1800</option>
                <option value="1900">1900</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
        </select>
        <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
        <input type="text" id="output" />
```

**Some notes and explanations:**

- You named some variables and then you tried to get them with different names which will cause an undefined variable/null reference error.
- The variable `price` can take a `string` as a value which leads to `NaN` in the output. In the snippet above, I changed all these lines `price = "Normal Rate";` with `price = 25;`.
- Your assigning `numbers` as `strings` (`price = "35"`), this works and `JavaScript` will cast it to number when it calculates, but, you want numbers why assign them as strings ?
- You're using `=` for comparisons and thats really wrong. You must either use `==` or `===` for comparisons.
- `=` is used for assignment.
- `==` is used for value comparisons.
- `===` is used for value and type comparisons.
- Try to avoid inline event handlers. `HTML` is, only, meant for page structure/markup. You should use `JavaScript` to do the task.

Hope I pushed you further.